# What is the MYSQL variant of time()?

Tags: php, mysql

In my script I store a PHP time() value in the database.
I've got a simple solution, but I bet it is certainly not the most 'clean' solution.

```
   <?php
   $time = time(); 
   mysql_query("DELETE FROM table WHERE expire < '$time';");
   ?>
```

**Is there an MySQL function with the same format as the PHP time() function?**

- my column is type INT(10)
- I just need to do a simple server-side comparison, I never have to display it.

Thanks in advance!
PS: Please support my English by correcting me :)

**EDIT:** I'll go with the UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), thanks all, for helping me and for discussing about the best option.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: It only took me 5 seconds to find the above link on google.

Comment: @SuperSpy: It's not helpful unless it does all the work for you and leaves you with no research or effort to put in on your own? Seriously? You're the only one who understands your requirements, and now you have the tools to satisfy them.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: I did research, but isn't this community for sharing knowledge? So why should I do hours of searching for the correct information if someone could help me by sharing his knowledge.
And... a downvote... really -.- ? Also I gave a 'clear' explanation about what I intend to do...

Comment: @SuperSpy: You were given the knowledge, then complained that "it's not helpful" because you'd still have to pick out your exact requirement from a documentation page full of delicious MySQL date/time functions!

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: I thought that you would understand that I was looking for an MYSQL function with the same output as time(). So far the unix_timestamp seemed most helpful :) BTW, I did not want to offend you! Sorry if my incorrect use of English implies otherwise.

Comment: @SuperSpy: No offence taken! It's just that no-one can tell you your requirements better than yourself, and now you have the reference that you needed to figure them out, which is great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(); // returns 1298999053 for example
```

so:

```
mysql_query("DELETE * FROM table WHERE expire < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()");
```

Comment: @AmirRaminfar well, the answer is `What is the MYSQL variant of time()?`, not `How can i store date in mysql`

Comment: don't excuse yourself with question. there are a crapload of bad questions, which shouldn't be answered at all. However, I don't think  unix timestamp is that bad.

Comment: True the question did ask a replacement for time(). I just wanted to show better programming practice.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is. You can use the now function.

```
mysql_query("DELETE * FROM table WHERE expire < NOW();");
```

**Edit:** I encourage you to use this function and not UNIX_TIMESTAMP. Reason is that you should have your column type as DATE and not long. In that case, you can do time functions on a date column where you can't easily do on a time stamp value.

Comment: @AmirRaminfar: Someone just downvoted both of us right now. :( I wonder why people do such things and not explain why they don't like the answer...

Comment: Yes indeed. I wonder why. You are encouraged to write a comment but this person didn't explain why.

Comment: Now() gives this format: '2007-12-15 23:50:26' where time() gives this format: 1298995533
So you can't compare them, or can you?

Comment: You can't compare them if you stick with using time() in PHP. You should change the column type to DATE and insert using NOW(). You will benefit from many DATE functions that are available to you. With DATE column type you can do things like <, >, <= etc...

Comment: You should always aim to represent your data closest to it's natural form. This means don't represent date as a string or an integer.

Comment: @Amir Raminfar: Even if the data is not for display purpose? And isn't an integer comparison faster than a date comparison? Keep in mind that the script must be as light weight as possible. Nevertheless thanks!

Comment: I'd downvote too, just for good company. unix timestamp isn't that bad, it served programmers for ages.

Comment: @SuperSpy the inner format of datatime is 8 bytes which is not that significant. I've never seen any problem with datetime performance before. and display purposes has nothing to do, as to display you'll have to format it anyway. that's realy matter of preferences and timestamp obvious limitations

Comment: @SuperSpy - As Col. Shrapnel  said, there is not performance loss. But here is a scenario with limitation. Let's say if decided to present everything with a timestamp. Tomorrow your boss comes to you and says I want you to give me a list of all records that were created in February. Using timestamp you would have to create the annoying math calculation to figure it out. If you had chosen a DATE format then you could have instead done MONTH(date_column) == 2 and really quickly filter. So yes its really what you prefer, but keep the future in mind I always say.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL the function is called now().

```
DELETE * FROM table WHERE expire < now();
```

Comment: Now() gives this format: '2007-12-15 23:50:26' where time() gives this format: 1298995533
So you can't compare them, or can you?

Comment: @SuperSpy - See Amir Raminfar's edit. The expire column should be of the type DATETIME and then NOW() is more suitable. If it's not in this format you are correct, but I would change it since DATETIME is much more useful in most cases.

Comment: well, the time() format which looks like '1298995533' is more efficient for the purpose... I do not need to display the time, my server only needs to compare a current time to an expire time. My column type is INT(10) which I figured will do the job.
Is there a better way?

Comment: @SuperSpy: it depends and they are both OK. I personally prefer datetime, because many of the time functions in MySQL use it, and when using unixtime I found that a lot of converting has to be done. Obviously it depends on the other queries you intend to run on the data.

Comment: None, the only thing I need to do is compare the current time to the expire time. And it would be nice if that could be done in the most efficient way. I think I'll go for the unix timestamp.